# Rotate Matrix for bitmap - Android

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, bearing

I have a custom map (canvas) that I am drawing a map pointer on. I am updating it in my onLocationChanged method of my main class, however I am struggling to get the bitmap to rotate. getBearing() doesn't seem to work (at least not for me) and so I am working to find the slope between points on the map. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void setBearing(Point prev, Point curr){

  float slope = 1;
  if (prev.x - curr.x !=0){
     slope = (float) ((y1-y2)/(x1-x2));
     bearing = (float) Math.atan(slope);
  }

}
```

...

```
Paint p = new Paint();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(bearing, coords.x, coords.y);
Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), 
                                          image.getHeight(), matrix, true);
canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedImage, x-image.getWidth()/2, y-image.getHeight()/2, p);
```

Edit:

Using latitude and longitude coordinates to find a bearing is more difficult than simply between two points. This code however (modified from code found [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)) works well:

```
public void setBearing(Location one, Location two){
  double lat1 = one.getLatitude();
  double lon1 = one.getLongitude();
  double lat2 = two.getLatitude();
  double lon2 = two.getLongitude();
  double deltaLon = lon2-lon1;
  double y = Math.sin(deltaLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
  double x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(deltaLon);
  bearing = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to rotate a bitmap: [Android: How to rotate a moving animated sprite based on the coordinates of its destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003823/android-how-to-rotate-a-moving-animated-sprite-based-on-the-coordinates-of-its/6004218#6004218)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know - is angle in degrees East of North, or is it in Radians (or is it something else)?

Comment: Angle is in degrees, the rest you will easily find after you try it.

Comment: Great, simple solution! Additionally, one reason why my bearing code doesn't work is that I am working with latitude/longitude coordinates. I found an easy fix for this (I'll update my post).

Comment: Cool, I'll have to favorite this for later when I need it. I see you have found Math.toDegrees() function - good to know. Does your atan2 produces angles from 0-90 or 0-360? I had to adjust this manually in my link.

Comment: Looks like my angles go from -180 to 180, which really makes this easy.

Comment: Great, in that case atan2 is the law! :)

Answer (score 2):

To correctly compute the angle with a minimum of fuss and division by zero risks, `atan2()` should be preferred to `atan()`. The following function returns the angle relative to the x-axis of a non-zero vector from `a` to `b`:

```
public float getBearing(Point a, Point b) { // Valid for a != b.
    float dx = b.x - a.x;
    float dy = b.y - a.y;
    return (float)Math.atan2(dy, dx);
}
```

I can't give advice on how to rotate the bitmap by a given angle, since I am not familiar with your API.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was wondering how to use atan2, so this was very helpful.

Comment: antonakos, atan2 is the correct way to do it, but since I am using lat/long coordinates, it made the problem more difficult. To post the code, I will update my post above to add this bearing code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to rotate ImageView

```
private void rotateImage(ImageView imageView, double angle) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); // required
    matrix.postRotate((float) angle, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds()
            .width() / 2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height() / 2);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```