# Skew and Rotate a bitmap in Android

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I'm working with the matrix and canvases for the first time and haven't been able to find a tutorial on this. I have been able to achieve good results with rotating a Bitmap only or skewing a Bitmap.

Currently I am able to rotate the image using:

```
Matrix.rotate(amount);
```

There are some other details to keep the shape centered around it's location as it rotates but that is not the main focus of my question.

What I want to do now is have the image rotate while being skewed into a different shape. Imagine, for example, how a spinning wheel looks when looking at it from any direction but exactly side on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this link. May be this helps you

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

try this as well

[Android: How to rotate a moving animated sprite based on the coordinates of its destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003823/android-how-to-rotate-a-moving-animated-sprite-based-on-the-coordinates-of-its/6004218#6004218)

Comment: Those are both great but the focus is more on skewing and rotation at the same time. What happens is mine ends up looking like a football that turns around.

It may be where I decide to skew the image that is the problem. Currently the process is:

1. image scaled
2. Apply to matrix
3. matrix skewed
4. matrix rotated
5. Repeat.
Should i be skewing the image before applying it to the matrix?
Or skewing the matrix after rotation?

Comment: I think first you should rotate image and skew it. Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
       matrix.postRotate(curRotate);
       matrix.postSkew(curSkewX, curSkewY);

Comment: I'll try that. I notice you suggest that I create the matrix every time. Is that intentional? If i don't do that will the matrix stay skewed?

Comment: yes you need to create matrix everytime, please try once doing this.